# How to initialise the h_n and h_c in LSTM?

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I try to use LSTM do to some classifications, and I see some examples where h_n and h_c are set to 0, can I initialise these two parameters with other values?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can initialize them with any values you want.

A sample random initialization of h_n and h_c would be:

```
h_n = torch.randn(num_layers * num_directions, batch_size, input_size).cuda().requires_grad_(True)
h_c = torch.randn(num_layers * num_directions, batch_size, input_size).cuda().requires_grad_(True)
```

num_layers is the number of layers that you have specified in your LSTM model and num_directions = 2 for bidirectional and 1 otherwise.

Note: Do .cuda() only if you want to train your model on a GPU.